# SQL - Showing only users who made a purchase in BOTH Q4 2021, and any date in 2022

Tags: sql

I want to run a SQL query to show only users who purchased BOTH in Q4 2021, and also purchased at any date in 2022. I don't want to show users who only purchased in one period or the other.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
    AND month(date(ORDER_PLACED)) IN ('10','11','12') 
    AND year(date(ORDER_PLACED)) in ('2021')
    AND year(date(ORDER_PLACED)) in ('2021')
```

Comment: Can you use a temporary table? What table is `ORDER_PLACED` in? Why not show a bit of the schema?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column ORDER_PLACED data type?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using MySQL, You can use INTERSECT clause -

```
SELECT user_id 
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
 WHERE ORDER_PLACED BETWEEN '01-10-2021' AND '12-31-2021'
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id 
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
 WHERE ORDER_PLACED BETWEEN '01-01-2022' AND '12-31-2022';
```